# Parameters SQL query dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, drop-down-menu, parameters

So, I finally got the following code to work.  It runs a different query based on selected value of the DDL.  Not, sure if its the best method.  Anyways, how do I go about using parameters directly in the below query?

I want to be able parameterized dbname and the database itself.  Thanks.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "")
    {
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "db1")
    {
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select db1.dbo.table1.dbname where dbname = 'testdb1' ", con);
            SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            Adpt.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "db2")
    {
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select db2.dbo.table1.dbname where dbname = 'testdb2' ", con);
            SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            Adpt.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put this ad the first line in your event `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` then in your `if{}else if()` just add the following `dt = new DataTable();` and remove this creating of a new instance `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` also how is the data being bound to the GridView1` initially..? if the dropdown is blank.. and the GridView1 is being Bound somewhere else.. then change the first if statement to 
`if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == string.Empty){ return}` also you do not need the additional `{ } inside the if else clauses

Comment: I will post the fix to your code also look up how to use Parameters when doing your Sql Select statements. do a search on the exact text 
`C# stackoverflow SqlCommand.Parameters.Add` or `C# stackoverflow SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWIthValue` for good working examples

Comment: Thanks for the link and the code fix.  I'll research using parameters and will post back if I need help.

Comment: if the re-write works please mark it as the acceptable answer..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter Adpt;
    if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue == string.Empty)
    {
        //return; 
        //GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        //GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "db1")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select db1.dbo.table1.dbname where dbname = 'testdb1' ", con);
        Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(dt);
    }
    else if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "db2")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select db2.dbo.table1.dbname where dbname = 'testdb2' ", con);
        Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(dt);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: 1 more question, do I need to worry about closing the connection?

Comment: you can refactor the code to use a `using(){}` construct and this will handle the auto disposing of the objects that were created using the `new` as well as the closing of the connection

Comment: `SqlConnection` implements `IDisposable` and you must take steps to make sure it's disposed. Wrap it in a using statement or close it in a `finally` block.

Comment: I am well aware of that as I have stated in my previous  comment perhaps you are having reading issues today..